# Application hang when do calling Web Services or any Network Call

Tags: android, android-intent

In the android app, When I start the activity its showing Black Screen or application hang on for few seconds. I want till the Black Screen I want to show the Progress bar. I tried many times but could not do this.

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" 
                + "<category><Id>" + catId + "</Id></category>";
StringBuilder resXML = new Connection().getResponseString("http://192.168.1.14/virtualMirror/productlisting.php", xml); // TODO URL change
if(!resXML.equals("")) {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(resXML.toString()); // getting DOM element
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Product");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductListing.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong("CategoryId", catId);
    bundle.putString("CategoryName", catName);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Use Aysnctask.. Look for examples in Google. There are a lot available

Comment: Look at my answer. its working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **AsyncTask.**

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

The AsyncTask executes everything in `doInBackground()` inside of another thread, which does not have access to the GUI where your views are.

`preExecute()` and `postExecute()` offer you access to GUI before and after the heavy lifting occurs in this new thread, you can even pass the result of the long operation to postExecute() to then show any results of processing.

```
class LoadCategory extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Pd = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        Pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"
                + "<category><Id>" + catId + "</Id></category>";

        StringBuilder resXML = new Connection().getResponseString("http://192.168.1.14/virtualMirror/productlisting.php",xml); // TODO URL change
        if (!resXML.equals("")) {
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(resXML.toString());
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Product");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Pd.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductListing.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong("CategoryId", catId);
        bundle.putString("CategoryName", catName);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And Use this class in your `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new LoadCategory().execute();
}
```

Comment: can't you explain why to use following? ^^^^

Comment: Sorry @LalitPoptani i edit my qestion and thanks for remembering me.. :)

Comment: doInBackground() invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing.

Comment: @hardik joshi i am getting this error after writing this code android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: @AjaySaini replace this Pd = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);

Answer (score 0):

You should first load the screen with progress bar and call this code using a new thread. For that, you can create a new class extending the thread class and override the run method. You will have to use the messages to get notification of the value is loaded.

Here is a quick and dirty example but hope will be sufficient for you to understand the overall flow.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
            if (total <= 0)
            {
            //Handle the response here
            } 
        }
    };

    private class yourclassname extends Thread{
        Handler mHandler;
        String _serviceUrl;
        CarpoolCancellationLoader(Handler h,String serviceUrl)
        {
            mHandler = h;
            _serviceUrl = serviceUrl;

        }

        private class SerializableClassName 
        {
        ..Put your serializable data here
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            cancelResponse = runJSONParser();
            //Send the thread activity done message to the handler
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", -1);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        }

          public YourResponseType runJSONParser()
          {
              try
              {
                //Perform your loading operation here
              }
              catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
          }

          public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
          {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

              String line = null;

              try
              {
                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
                  }
              }
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally
              {
                  try
                  {
                      is.close();
                  }
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }

              return sb.toString();
          }
    }
```

This is not pretty clean code though but will be sufficient to give you an overall idea of the structure of code that creates new thread and obtains result by running it asynchronously.